# How to create multiple named ranges with a fixed size from one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I am wondering if there is a way to create named ranges with a fixed size (252 cells) from one column.

I have 51,156 numbers in column B. I want the first 252 numbers (`B1:B252`) to become named range `RANGE1`.

Then I want `B253-B504` to become named range `RANGE2`. Et cetera.

Does anyone know a way? Normally I would just select the ranges and type a name, but now I have to do this for approx. 200 ranges per sheet in 25 sheets.

Thanks!

I have perhaps made the task a little bit easier. I now have in Column C (`C1:C202`) the names I want the named ranges to become, and in Column D the input for the arrays as how the Named Range Menu reads them (`D1` contains `=first14!L1:L252` , `D2` contains `=first14!L253:L504` et cetera).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with VBA. You'll need to modify the constants at the top if your sheets aren't all the same. It uses the currently active sheet so select the one you want before running the macro.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddNamedRanges()
    Const NumberOfRanges As Long = 202      'How many ranges to create
    Const HeightOfRanges As Long = 252      'How tall to make each range
    Const RefersToColumn As Integer = "B"   'Which column to reference
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To NumberOfRanges
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "RANGE" & r, ActiveSheet.Range(RefersToColumn & (r - 1) * HeightOfRanges + 1 & ":" & RefersToColumn & r * HeightOfRanges)
    Next
End Sub
```